# Как сделать путь установки с помощью SceneBuilder и JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Никак не могу найти как сделать путь установки как на этом изображении(С помощью SceneBuilder и JavaFX):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создайте представление в SceneBuilder install.fxml.
Расположите элемент AnchorPane и в нем поместите элементы Button (обзор, далее, отмена)  и TextField как Вам нравится.
Примерное содержание install.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="500.0" maxWidth="600.0" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fezas.telegra.controllers.InstallController">
    <children>
        <Button id="saveButton" fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="454.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveSetting" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Далее" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="136.0" />
        <Button fx:id="closeButton" cancelButton="true" layoutX="466.0" layoutY="454.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Отмена" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" />
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            <children>
                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="27.0" text="Каталог:" />
                <Button fx:id="btnSelectCat" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectCat" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="68.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0;" text="Обзор" />
                <TextField fx:id="textFieldSelectCat" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="322.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 3 0 0 3;" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Контроллер InstallController.java

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class InstallController implements Initializable {

    @FXML    private Button btnSelectCat, closeButton;
    @FXML    private TextField textFieldSelectCat, textFieldSelectCat;;

    @FXML
    void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void selectCat(ActionEvent event) {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        File dir = directoryChooser.showDialog(btnSelectCat.getScene().getWindow());
        directoryChooser.setTitle("Выбор каталога");
        if (dir != null) {
            textFieldSelectCat.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        textFieldSelectCat.setText(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    }
}
```

Запустите свою форму:

```
public class InstallApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("install.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Установка");
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```